SPFx Webpart to retrieve term store terms
I am working on a simple SPFx webpart with minimal framework (no react), to retrieve terms from the term store. I am following the instructions from the PnP site but running into an issue I cannot figure out.
private async _getTermStoreTerms(){
  const graph = graphfi().using(SPFx(this.context));
  const infos:ITermSet = await graph.termStore.groups.getById("<groupId>").sets.getById("<setid>").terms();

  console.log(infos);
}

This function is generating the following error when I try to run into in a local debugging session started with Gulp Server --Nobrowser.
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'groups')
at SearchFiltersWebPart.<anonymous> (SearchFiltersWebPart.tsx:40:52)
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at -search-filters-web-part.js:3120:71
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at uEB3.__awaiter (-search-filters-web-part.js:3116:12)
at SearchFiltersWebPart._getTermStoreTerms (SearchFiltersWebPart.tsx:37:35)
at SearchFiltersWebPart.render (SearchFiltersWebPart.tsx:33:10)
at i._renderWithAccessibleTitle (sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_6943ced402b53a902bfc18b8cca21adb.js:243:44708)
at sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_6943ced402b53a902bfc18b8cca21adb.js:243:44168

I have verified the IDs for both the group and term set. I read something about requiring that your web part be authorized to access graph which I added to the package-solution.json file but it doesn't seem to do anything.
"webApiPermissionRequests": [
  {
    "resource": "Microsoft Graph",
    "scope": "TermStore.Read.All"
  }
]

I'm out of ideas. Please help.
Update
I ended up deploying an incomplete version of the solution and was able to approve the requested permissions. However, this did not resolve the issue.
Second Update
Turns out that graph.termStore is undefined. Still no idea what I'm doing wrong.
